# IntegerProperty cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Integer>

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

Работаю с TableView (две колонки) в JavaFX, создал конструктор и передаю начальные данные. В первую тип String, во вторую Integer, сделал все индетично, но вот со стрингом все работает, а с Integer нет. Помогите разобраться, что именно я упускаю.

Класс Main где заполняю первоначальные данные

```
private ObservableList<TableIncome> incomeData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public Main() {
    // В качестве образца добавляем некоторые данные
    incomeData.add(new TableIncome("Доход1", 0));
    incomeData.add(new TableIncome("Доход2", 0));
    incomeData.add(new TableIncome("Доход3", 0));
}
```

Тут класс контроллер, где я объявляю некоторые переменные и произвожу заполнение таблицы.

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<TableIncome> tableIncomeTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TableIncome, String> typeIncome;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TableIncome, Integer> janIncome;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Инициализация таблицы адресатов с двумя столбцами.
        typeIncome.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().typeProperty());
        janIncome.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().januaryProperty());
    }
```

И сам класс TableIncome, где расположен конструктор.

```
public class TableIncome {
    private StringProperty type;
    private IntegerProperty january;

 public TableIncome(String type, Integer january){
        this.type = new SimpleStringProperty (type);
        this.january = new SimpleIntegerProperty(january);
}

public StringProperty typeProperty() {
    return type;
}

public IntegerProperty januaryProperty() {
    return january;
}
```

Т.е. сама ошибка указывает на `cellData.getValue().januaryProperty());`, с текстом ошибки `Bad return type in lambda expression: IntegerProperty cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Integer>`

Класс TableIncome

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 * Хранение данных для таблицы "Тип дохода"
 */

public class TableIncome {
    private StringProperty type;

    private IntegerProperty january;
    private IntegerProperty february;
    private IntegerProperty march;
    private IntegerProperty april;
    private IntegerProperty may;
    private IntegerProperty june;
    private IntegerProperty jule;
    private IntegerProperty august;
    private IntegerProperty september;
    private IntegerProperty october;
    private IntegerProperty november;
    private IntegerProperty december;

    public TableIncome(){
        this(null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор с начальными данными
     * @param type
     */
    public TableIncome(String type, Integer january){
        this.type = new SimpleStringProperty (type);
        this.january = new SimpleIntegerProperty(january);
        /**
         * начальные данные
         */
//        this.january = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        this.february = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.march = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.april = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.may = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.june = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.jule = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.august = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.september = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.october = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.november = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.december = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type.get();
    }

    public StringProperty typeProperty() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type.set(type);
    }

    public int getJanuary() {
        return january.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty januaryProperty() {
        return january;
    }

    public void setJanuary(int january) {
        this.january.set(january);
    }

    public int getFebruary() {
        return february.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty februaryProperty() {
        return february;
    }

    public void setFebruary(int february) {
        this.february.set(february);
    }

    public int getMarch() {
        return march.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty marchProperty() {
        return march;
    }

    public void setMarch(int march) {
        this.march.set(march);
    }

    public int getApril() {
        return april.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty aprilProperty() {
        return april;
    }

    public void setApril(int april) {
        this.april.set(april);
    }

    public int getMay() {
        return may.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty mayProperty() {
        return may;
    }

    public void setMay(int may) {
        this.may.set(may);
    }

    public int getJune() {
        return june.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty juneProperty() {
        return june;
    }

    public void setJune(int june) {
        this.june.set(june);
    }

    public int getJule() {
        return jule.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty juleProperty() {
        return jule;
    }

    public void setJule(int jule) {
        this.jule.set(jule);
    }

    public int getAugust() {
        return august.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty augustProperty() {
        return august;
    }

    public void setAugust(int august) {
        this.august.set(august);
    }

    public int getSeptember() {
        return september.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty septemberProperty() {
        return september;
    }

    public void setSeptember(int september) {
        this.september.set(september);
    }

    public int getOctober() {
        return october.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty octoberProperty() {
        return october;
    }

    public void setOctober(int october) {
        this.october.set(october);
    }

    public int getNovember() {
        return november.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty novemberProperty() {
        return november;
    }

    public void setNovember(int november) {
        this.november.set(november);
    }

    public int getDecember() {
        return december.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty decemberProperty() {
        return december;
    }

    public void setDecember(int december) {
        this.december.set(december);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите класс `IntegerProperty`. в `lamda` нужно `integer` значение, возможно оно хранится в `IntegerProperty`.

Comment: Согласен, я бы тоже в POJO убрал Property, оно у вас и так в обсервабле, так еще и внутри проперти, масло масляное.

Comment: @Maxim я правильно понимаю, что вы предлагаете в `januaryProperty` оставить тип просто `Integer`? Ну и соответственно переделать `private IntegerProperty january;`, где тип будет просто `Integer`? я просто так пробовал, не получилось, да и почему со String все работает?

Comment: @AntonSorokin простите не очень понял, вы пишите - "Приведите класс", в смысле выложить его полностью?

Comment: Если в ответах ничего толкового не предложат, поменяйте в `TableColumn<TableIncome, Integer> janIncome` `Integer` на `Number`, либо добавьте в POJO геттеры и сеттеры и используйте `PropertyValueFactory` ([пример](https://books.google.ru/books?id=InxeDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA200&ots=6SNOQq8neb&pg=PA198)).

Comment: @VladislavZherikhov да. Есть в нем integer поля?

Comment: @AntonSorokin выложил класс `TableIncome`
полей именно Integer там нет, поля типа `IntegerProperty` находятся только в этом классе

Comment: @VladislavZherikhov ааа, не очень знаком с FX, я думал IP - это ваш класс, а это класс FX. Попробуйте написать januaryProperty.getValue(); в лямбде.

Comment: @AntonSorokin ошибка все та же, меня смущает то, что все это прекрасно работает со Стринг

Comment: Помог совет @zRrr, но пока не понял почему именно так, буду разбираться

Comment: @VladislavZherikhov там не может быть такой же ошибки. januaryProperty - это IntegerProperty. IntegerProperty.getValue() - должен возвращать integer, а это и нужно в лямбде

Comment: @AntonSorokin ну да, простите, ошибка немного изменилась `Bad return type in lambda expression: Integer cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Integer>` - сейчас выдает это (c getValue), а предыдущий вариант - `Bad return type in lambda expression: IntegerProperty cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Integer>`

Comment: в классе `TableIncome` замените `IntegerProperty` на `ObservableValue<Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перевести IntegerProperty в объект.

`ObservableValue<Integer> obsInt = new IntegerProperty(intValue).asObject();`